# I cannot solve this simple looking trigonometric question

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, area

Long story short, we are having a High School Geometry test tomorrow, and as I was practicing a came accross a trigonometry task in my textbook, which looked simple, but I couldn't figure out the way to solve it.

The task here is to find the area of the whole polygon. According to the textbook's answer sheet, the answer is 428 square the centimeters (the other values on the image are in centimeters).

[image: This is the image for the task.]

I could easily figure out the sides of the bottom 4 triangles with the pythegorian theorem, and their area can be easily calculated with Heron's formula, but I cannot solve the top 2 triangles. I would appreciate if you could give me any help with that.

Comment: area of the top triangle is $7\cdot 14$ (you are given a side and a height)

Comment: Honestly, as the image is drawn, there really isn't a correct answer.  If we are supposed to assume that the dashed lines are perpendicular to the diagonals of the pentagon, then use the fact that the area of a triangle is $\frac{1}{2} bh$, where $b$ is the length of the base (corresponding to one of the diagonals), and $h$ is the height (corresponding to one of the dashed lines).

Comment: Thank you to you both. Now I see that I majorly overcomplicated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Area of top triangle: $\dfrac{7\times 28}{2}$ = $7\times 14$ = $98$

Area of middle triangle: $\dfrac{30\times 12}{2}$ = $30\times 6$ = $180$

Area of bottom triangle: $\dfrac{30\times 10}{2}$ = $30\times 5$ = $150$

Adding them together: $428$

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea why I was making this so complicated for myself.

Comment: Glad I helped! Don't worry, I know how you feel! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the polygon has been broken into triangles, with heights given. The area of a triangle is one-half the length of the base times the height.

Comment: Oh my god. Now I feel stupid (I might be tbh). That is the simplest way to calculate the area and never even thought about it. Thank you so much. I hope this example will change my approach to these types of tasks.